# Why adding new document with irrelevant content destroy search score and search relevant documents order?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to figure out why adding new document with irrelevant content destroy search score results.

I wrote this simle code:

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch


def add_document(es, index_name, content, place, id):
    body = {}
    body["content"] = content
    body["place"] = place
    es.index(index=index_name, body=body, id=id)
    es.indices.refresh(index=index_name)



def get_results(es, index_name, query, place):

    search_query = {
        "query": {
            "bool": {

                "must":
                    [{
                        "query_string": {
                            "default_field": "content",
                            "query":  query
                            }
                    }]
            }
        }
    }

    if place is not None:
        should_query = {
                       "terms": {
                            "place":  [place]
                       }}
        search_query["query"]["bool"]["should"] = should_query

    res = es.search(index=index_name, body=search_query)
    print(f"\nTotal number of results: {len(res['hits']['hits'])}, For query: {query}, Place: {place}")
    for i in range(len(res['hits']['hits'])):
        print(f"Doc id: {res['hits']['hits'][i]['_id']} "
              f" ,Score: {res['hits']['hits'][i]['_score']}, "
              f" ,Place: {res['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['place']}"
              f" ,Content: {res['hits']['hits'][i]['_source']['content']}")


def main():

    es         = Elasticsearch()
    index_name = "demo_idx"

    # delete old content
    if es.indices.exists(index=index_name) is True:
        es.indices.delete(index=index_name)

    add_document(es=es,
                 index_name=index_name,
                 content="Distributed nature, simple REST APIs, speed, and scalability",
                 place="html",
                 id=1)
    add_document(es=es,
                 index_name=index_name,
                 content="Distributed nature, simple APIs, speed, and scalability",
                 place="html",
                 id=2)
    add_document(es=es,
                 index_name=index_name,
                 content="Known for its simple REST APIs, distributed nature, speed, and scalability, Elasticsearch is the central component of the Elastic Stack, a set of open source tools for data ingestion, enrichment, storage, analysis, and visualization.",
                 place="javascript",
                 id=3)

    get_results(es=es, index_name=index_name, query="simple rest apis distributed nature", place=None)
    get_results(es=es, index_name=index_name, query="simple rest apis distributed nature", place="javascript")

    add_document(es=es,
                 index_name=index_name,
                 content="national geographic",
                 place="javascript",
                 id=4)
    
    get_results(es=es, index_name=index_name, query="simple rest apis distributed nature", place=None)
    get_results(es=es, index_name=index_name, query="simple rest apis distributed nature", place="javascript")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And I got the following results:

```
Total number of results: 3, For query: simple rest apis distributed nature, Place: None
Doc id: 1  ,Score: 1.2689934,  ,Place: html ,Content: Distributed nature, simple REST APIs, speed, and scalability
Doc id: 2  ,Score: 0.6970792,  ,Place: html ,Content: Distributed nature, simple APIs, speed, and scalability
Doc id: 3  ,Score: 0.69611007,  ,Place: javascript ,Content: Known for its simple REST APIs, distributed nature, speed, and scalability, Elasticsearch is the central component of the Elastic Stack, a set of open source tools for data ingestion, enrichment, storage, analysis, and visualization.

Total number of results: 3, For query: simple rest apis distributed nature, Place: javascript
Doc id: 3  ,Score: 1.69611,  ,Place: javascript ,Content: Known for its simple REST APIs, distributed nature, speed, and scalability, Elasticsearch is the central component of the Elastic Stack, a set of open source tools for data ingestion, enrichment, storage, analysis, and visualization.
Doc id: 1  ,Score: 1.2689934,  ,Place: html ,Content: Distributed nature, simple REST APIs, speed, and scalability
Doc id: 2  ,Score: 0.6970792,  ,Place: html ,Content: Distributed nature, simple APIs, speed, and scalability

Total number of results: 3, For query: simple rest apis distributed nature, Place: None
Doc id: 1  ,Score: 2.5010183,  ,Place: html ,Content: Distributed nature, simple REST APIs, speed, and scalability
Doc id: 2  ,Score: 1.7494614,  ,Place: html ,Content: Distributed nature, simple APIs, speed, and scalability
Doc id: 3  ,Score: 1.2604496,  ,Place: javascript ,Content: Known for its simple REST APIs, distributed nature, speed, and scalability, Elasticsearch is the central component of the Elastic Stack, a set of open source tools for data ingestion, enrichment, storage, analysis, and visualization.

Total number of results: 3, For query: simple rest apis distributed nature, Place: javascript
Doc id: 1  ,Score: 2.5010183,  ,Place: html ,Content: Distributed nature, simple REST APIs, speed, and scalability
Doc id: 3  ,Score: 2.2604496,  ,Place: javascript ,Content: Known for its simple REST APIs, distributed nature, speed, and scalability, Elasticsearch is the central component of the Elastic Stack, a set of open source tools for data ingestion, enrichment, storage, analysis, and visualization.
Doc id: 2  ,Score: 1.7494614,  ,Place: html ,Content: Distributed nature, simple APIs, speed, and scalability
```

As you can see, before adding the new document (`id=4`) I'm getting that document with `id=3` has the highest score results when searching with `place = javascript`.

But after adding new document (`id=4`, with irrelevant content and same place field (`javascript`), searching with same query and same place gives that document `id=3` dosn't have highest score.

- I'm using `elasticsearch:7.6.2`

- What is the explanation for the results I received?
- Why are they right?

Comment: Which ES version are you using?

Comment: elasticsearch:7.6.2